# Philosophy and science

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Is philosophy still considered as 'mother of science' nowadays? Because i don't know relevance philosophy with the term mother of science in this days. (21st Century)

Comment: No, it is not....

Comment: Duplicate of [PhilSE: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24699/philosophy-is-the-mother-of-all-science](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24699/philosophy-is-the-mother-of-all-science) See links in question for guidance.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: I'm voted to close to consolidate with other post to try to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics is known as the queen of sciences.  When we call a science mother, it must be able to produce other sciences. Of course there must be some philosophy behind each science. But there must be sciences before philosophy was born. Though there is observation, thought process etc. in philosophy, we can never say that the first thought was about the **fundamentals** of nature of knowledge, reality, and existence.

Sometimes each expert in other subjects would claim their subject as the mother of all sciences. If you are searching for a science giving importance to these aspects also, no subject that is being treated as science has the quality of a mother.

Though we can't say there is one such **science** that can produce other science, there must be *something* that keeps 'motherly subtle nature' and **console like a mother**.  But most often people don't like to call it science or mother because it often seems 'naked -- without any ego' and careless about its progeny.

The following link would throw light on in this regard:

[Is Philosophy the source of all other fields of study?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48547/is-philosophy-the-source-of-all-other-fields-of-study/48560#48560)